# Validating a BCrypt.Net password without storing the salt?

Tags: c#, bcrypt

So i'm looking to implement a log in form on a site i am designing and while i have the passwords salting and hashing before being saved to my DB, i am struggling badly to allow the user to log in as the salt is not being saved.

I spoke to someone about this and they advised me it is possible to use this method of encryption without saving the salt, but i have no idea how this is possible.

I did ask the person, and he emailed me some code but unfortunately it was sent to my work email address and i forgot to send it home...doh!

So i am putting the users into the DB using the following:

```
string pwdToHash = userDetails.PassWord;
string hashToStoreInDatabase = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(pwdToHash, BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(12));
```

Now for my log in:

```
string mySalt = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(12);
        string myHash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(PassWord);

        bool doesPasswordMatch = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(myHash, mySalt);
```

now i am aware that i am generating a new salt with the log in part of the code, but if i am not saving the salt, how on earth can i know what it was?

Am i being led down a garden path with this advice or is it possible without storing the salt?

Cheers

Comment: It'd need to be a predictable salt. Like if you used the username as the salt for the password, for example.

Comment: It's a pretty common technique to store the salt alongside the hashed password.  UNIX has been doing it for 40+ years (although the password algorithms being used have changed over the years... SHA-512 seems to be the current standard and the salt length went from 2 characters to 16 characters).

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to store a salt. But, if you really don't, you can use a piece of information unique to the user to compute one at runtime. Something to use like this could be their account creation date either in an epoch or ticks.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the input but i figured out what i was doing wrong

i salt and hash the password when it is created, but i was generating a new hash when trying to log in, so it was always returning true...doh!

i am now using the created hash upon registration and verifying that against the password they entered. All working now.

Thanks